# How can I load a specific part of webpage in UIWebView ??

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I need to load or hide a part of a web page that can be viewed in my WebView.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que ca veut dire ? Je ne comprends pas...

Comment: google translator please..

Comment: (Also known in the FAQ as: Stack Overflow is an English-only site.)

Comment: as @H2CO3 said, c'est un site anglais. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two StackOverflow questions - between them, you should be able to solve your problem.

First: 
[Objective C - UIWebview to load only a certain part of the webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780700/objective-c-uiwebview-to-load-only-a-certain-part-of-the-webpage)

Then, take a look at:
[Reading HTML content from a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992348/reading-html-content-from-a-uiwebview)